# How do you get the Firebase/Crashlytics uploaded dsyms to register for stastical modeling and percentages?

Tags: ios, firebase, upload, crashlytics, dsym

We have used a various methods to upload dSYMS to firebase (script, manual, etc.) for our iOS app. They all get accepted and you can see the optional vs required in the dashboard:
[image: Firebase crash dlsym table]

The problem is it seems the crash status is never calculated because these dSYMs aren't received ...even though they were uploaded.

**Have you ever experienced this?  How does your team handle this?**

Answer (score 0):

Check that Xcode is generating dSYMs, check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#check-xcode)

If bitcode was enabled and the app released to the App Store or if you are using TestFlight, you will need to download the dSYMs from the App Store and then upload them. Check this [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#expandable-1).

Also, make sure you are using the latest SDK version. I had an issue where the dSYM file I  was uploading had the same UUID that was shown in the dashboard but still it wasn't processed, updating the version solved it.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo. That's what I'm saying. I'm able to upload the dSYMs to FB and they get accepted.   Then 1 - 2 days, a new missing dSYM shows up.

Comment: Is this after pushing a new version of the app? If this is the case, that is expected. When making any code changes in the app and then it gets bult, a new UUID and dSYMs will be generated, so those new dSYMs need to be uploaded too.